# Layout not getting GONE sometimes in android

Tags: android

I have a relative layout with an image and title.Below the relativelayout I have an Editext(used for searching which will display a search result listview based on change of text in the edittext).So once i touch on the EDITExt softkeyboard will appear and the top layout's visibility is set to 'Gone'.It works fine but sometimes the edittext moves up but the top layout is visible like ui frozen and this will disapppear when we enter a keystroke for edittext.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/violetbg"
      android:id="@+id/parentt"
    >
      <FrameLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/framestepone"



     />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/framestepone"
         >
      <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_height="@dimen/titlebarsize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:id="@+id/topbar"
        >
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           style="@style/actionbarphonetextviewstyle"
            android:text="@string/steponetitle"
          android:id="@+id/steponetitle"
            />

        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sidemenutest"
            android:id="@+id/sidemenu"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/initlay"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/topbar"
          android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/layyy"


             >

      <TextView 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/steptag"
        android:text="@string/steptagg"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/titletextsize"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/steponetag"
        android:text="@string/onetag"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/titletextsize"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/steptag"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />
    <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/steponebg"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/stepone"
      android:layout_below="@+id/steponetag"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       />
     <TextView 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/steponetext"
        android:text="@string/chooser"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/titletextsize"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/steponebg"
          android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />   
        </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relativebag"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_below="@+id/initlay"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

        >
        <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relativebagforlist"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >
        <EditText 
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:hint="Search &amp; Preview Song"
            android:id="@+id/searchsong"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
           android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
           android:background="@drawable/steponetextboxbg"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
           android:singleLine="true"
             android:paddingLeft="12dp"
           android:imeOptions="actionDone"
             android:paddingRight="8dp"
            />


        <RelativeLayout 
           android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true"
               android:background="@drawable/steponetextboxbg"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
           android:id="@+id/parntrecrd"

            >
            <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/lay"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                >
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/playbtns"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/play"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                />
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/pausebtns"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/pause"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtsearche"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lay"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="search song"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

        </RelativeLayout>


         </RelativeLayout>
         <ImageButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/question"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativebagforlist"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativebagforlist"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnhelp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />
         <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnhelp"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnhelp"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnhelp"
             android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/relativebagforlist"
              >
         <TextView 

             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hlptxt"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
             android:text="@string/help"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

             />
         </RelativeLayout>
        <Button 
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnheights"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:text="@string/readybutton"
            android:id="@+id/btnready"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
         android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
           style="@style/actionbarphonetextviewstyle"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"

            />

          <ListView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:id="@+id/lstsongs"
           android:background="@color/white"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:visibility="gone"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/relativebagforlist"



            />
      <TextView 
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativebagforlist"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/nomatch"
            android:id="@+id/nomatchtext"     
            android:textColor="@color/black"
           android:paddingLeft="10dp"    
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>




    <!--     ********************************************     -->


 <ImageView 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/progrest"
       android:visibility="gone"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"

       />

     </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my code after clicking the textview which will invoke the softkeyboard making the edittext visible and top layout gone is as follows

```
txtsearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                temptext=(txtsearch.getText().toString());

                help.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                helptext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtrecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                searchsong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                steptag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                steponetag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                steponebg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                steponetext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                searchsong.requestFocus();

                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.showSoftInput(searchsong, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
                searchsong.setText(temptext);
                if(myMap.size()==0){

                     new Getsongs().execute();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: The edittext might be having the property `android:layout_below:"THAT TOP VIEW"`. Then again, I can only guess without code.

Comment: but it's showing this scenario in only some situations not in all situaations.And also the textview/editext is not set below the layout which I am setting to gone.It's below the parent layout of this disappearing layout.

Comment: @Tushar please go through my code and suggest me a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"`

from my manifest